# $f(B)\ne\mathbb{K}$. Linear Functional is Bounded $\iff$ $f(B)\ne\mathbb{K}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}\text{-or-}\mathbb{C}$. I am trying to prove linear functional $f$ on $X$ is continuous if and only if $f(B)\ne\mathbb{K}$, where $B=\overline{B}_X(0;1)$.

I have know that $f$ is bounded if and only if $\{\text{ }|f(x)|\text{ }|\text{ }\|x\|\leq 1\text{ }\}=|f(B)|$ is a bounded set (i.e. finite supremum).

For the forward implication, clearly if the set is bounded, then it cannot equal the whole of $\mathbb{K}$.

I just need the converse? Anyone?

Comment: One might consider the definition of a bounded linear functional, in terms of operator norms or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(B)\neq\mathbb{K}$, then there exists some $y\in\mathbb{K}$ such that $y\neq f(B)$. If there is $x\in B$ such that $|f(x)|>|y|$, then choosing  $t= \frac{y}{f(x)}$ you have $|t|<1$ and so $tx\in B$. Moreover, $f(t x)=y$, contradicting the choice of $y$ as being not in $f(B)$. It follows that there is no $x\in B$ such that $|f(x)|>|y|$ and so $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in B$ and consider $r:= |f(x)|$, then

a) Replacing $x$ by $\lambda x$ for $|\lambda| = 1$, check that $f(B)$ contains the circle
$$
\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = r\}
$$

b) Replacing $x$ by $\lambda x$ for $|\lambda| \leq 1$, check that $f(B)$ contains the disk
$$
\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq r\}
$$

c) Now if $f$ is unbounded, $\exists (x_n) \subset B$ such that $r_n := |f(x_n)| \to \infty$. Now use (a) and (b) to conclude that $f(B) = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Very Interesting.